# ul li attach each click to add a openToggle class

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am having some issues, trying to figure out a way to attach a dynamic menu toggle when clicking something specific within a post in a ul li list. However, for some kind of reason it does not work perfectly well.

I was thinking about Each(); and Closest(); + Find(); in jQuery.

Here's a picture of what I want to achieve:

[image]

Any help is welcome! Thanks, hope the solution can be dynamic.

Code:

```
  var activeClass = 'openToggler', showingDropdown, showingMenu, showingParent;
        /* hides the current menu */
        var hideMenu = function () {
            if (showingDropdown) {
                showingDropdown.removeClass(activeClass);
                showingMenu.hide();
            }
        };

        /* recurse through dropdown menus */
        $('.micro-post').each(function () {
            /* track elements: menu, parent */
            var dropdown = $(this);
            //var opts = dropdown.closest("opts");

            //console.log(opts);

            var menu = dropdown.next('.dropdown-menu'), parent = dropdown.parent();
            /* function that shows THIS menu */
            var showMenu = function () {
                hideMenu();
                showingDropdown = $(this).closest('.micro-post').addClass(activeClass);
                showingMenu = menu.show();
                showingParent = parent;
            };
            /* function to show menu when clicked */
            dropdown.bind('click', function (e) {
                if (e) e.stopPropagation();
                if (e) e.preventDefault();
                showMenu();
            });
            /* function to show menu when someone tabs to the box */
            dropdown.bind('focus', function () {
                showMenu();
            });
        });

        /* hide when clicked outside */
        $(document.body, ".micro-post").bind('click', function (e) {
            if (showingParent) {
                var parentElement = showingParent[0];
                if (!$.contains(parentElement, e.target) || !parentElement == e.target) {
                    hideMenu();
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Any link to any example is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, thanks for the help, but after re-writing everything I figured-out a way to solve it and my own solution works perfectly now. Thanks a lot for trying to help me, but I am done. If I ever encounter any issues, I will post here, StackOverFlow Rocks! :)